# Colors alternate every row between blue and white in an Excel spreadsheet

Tags: word-usage, word-request

Can anyone advise me on how to describe the following condition of an Excel spreadsheet:

Row 1 is colored with blue.
Row 2 is colored with white.
Row 3 is colored with blue.
Row 4 is colored with white.
Row 5 is colored with blue.
...

Can this condition be described that colors alternate every row between blue and white ?

Comment: **Striped rows** is the term for using color to highlight rows, [**zebra striping**](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_tables.asp) is the term for alternating row colors in a table, `<table class="table table-striped">` is the Bootstrap HTML notation to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Can this condition be described that colors alternate every row between blue and white?*

Absolutely.  That is an admirably clear way of describing it.  Or we might say:

> The rows are alternately blue and white.

Comment: If it's a given that the default color is white, one might also say, "Every other row is blue." (The two-word phrase _every other_ is an idiom that could be applied here.)

Answer (score 0):

The term I see the most for this is [zebra striping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zebra_striping_(computer_graphics)#Table_zebra_striping).

> The term is also used for tables with every other row colored to make it easier to read tables. Although Zebra striping has been used for a long time to improve readability, there is relatively little data on how much it helps.

Even though zebras are black & white, the term applies regardless of the actual colors used.